# PySource Tracker.py file

Tags: python, pycharm, object-tracking

This is trivial but something prevents me from downloading the souce files and tracker.py file from PySource for Object Tracking with Opencv and Python by Sergio Canu. Could anyone share it if they have it?

I tried subscribing with several emails (and confirmed them) but the website just doesn't recognise it no matter how long has passed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: voting to close. not programming.